# Is it true that Netscape Navigator eventually became Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: history, netscape

Is it really the case that Mozilla Firefox is a modern day version of Netscape Navigator?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105983/discussion-on-question-by-neil-meyer-is-it-true-that-netscape-navigator-eventual).

Comment: I still feel this is a very trivial question; the answer is effectively "yes", and everything else is off-topic discussion. I've asked a more specific question here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14229/is-there-any-code-in-firefox-as-of-2020-that-comes-from-netscape-navigator

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, it’s true, as explained in Wikipedia’s entries for [the Mozilla application suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite#History_and_development) and [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#History). More accurately, Firefox is a descendant of Netscape Navigator; most of Firefox has been rewritten in one way or another since the days of Navigator.

Most of Netscape Navigator (or rather, Communicator) was released as open source in 1998; this was then extensively rewritten and eventually emerged as the Mozilla application suite. Some of Netscape’s engineers started developing a subset of the suite to produce a nimble browser, and that eventually became Firefox (after conflicts over its previous names, Phoenix and Firebird).

The initial Mozilla rewrite took four years, and ended up being used as [as an example of why not to rewrite software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/) (see also [Wikipedia’s entry on the history of the suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mozilla_Application_Suite)).

Comment: With seamonkey one can relive the Netscape Communicator suite feelling. I used it for a long time on my work PC.
http://www.seamonkey-project.org/

Comment: "an example of why not to rewrite software" - if your software is **non-trivial** and **actively maintained** the whole time. CRUD frontends are rewritten all the time, after the client decides that after 10 years of only necessary bugfixes and 0 development he now wants a new features.

Comment: The reason that the source had to be rewritten was because it never was production quality in the first place because it too was a rewrite that shouldn't have been done.  If Netscape 3 had been open sourced instead, the browser wars might have had quite a different outcome.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Do you mean Netscape 4 (before anything was open sourced) was a rewrite which shouldn't have happened, and was "not production quality" (even though it was publicly released)? Or were you just misremembering the version number, and saying that the unfinished  Netscape 5 code had already had heavy rewrites before the Mozilla Foundation took over?

Comment: @imsop 4 was the communicator which was quite usable.  The failed rewrite from scratch (which the open source community threw out after the initial excitement ) was the supposed Netscape 5. I liked Netscape 3 Gold better.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That description doesn't match any of the accounts I've read. The rewrites had started, but Netscape were planning to wait until they were ready; it was the open source community that decided to throw away the _old_ code and focus on the rewrites.